# Show message before redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I insert the customer details,a message **'Thank You!Your details has been successfully registered.'** is shown. I want to redirect to another page after showing this message.
Regards,
David

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a `Literal` control into .aspx

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
```

and following code in save button's click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  Literal1.Text= "Thank You!Your details has been successfully registered, <script> 
       setTimeout(function() { window.location='newpage.aspx';},1000); </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a message you have to return html instead of doing a server side redirect. You can then do a client redirect, either with javascript or with a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://yoursite.com/thepageyouwanttoredirectto.aspx">
```

Comment: ...I tried                 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "message", "alert('Thank You!Your details has been successfully registered.');location.href = 'Cust_Home.aspx';", true);